# Symfony-CMF Fixtures Not creating

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-cmf

I've searched all the manuals for the answer, but can not find it at all.

I'm trying to apply the CMF to my existing Symfony 2 project using this doc: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/tutorials/creating_cms_using_cmf_and_sonata.html

Then, I've got the Tree problems explained here: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/tutorials/creating_cms_using_cmf_and_sonata.html#tree-problems

And I tried to fill some fixtures using PHPCR like it explained here: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/tutorials/using_blockbundle_and_contentbundle.html#using-the-phpcr

But I had no luck at all with this strange red-backgrounded error:

> The class 'Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\BlockBundle\Doctrine\Phpcr\SimpleBlock' was not found in the chain configured namespaces Doctrine\ODM\PHPCR\Document, Symfony\Component\Routing, Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\RoutingBundle\Model, Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\RoutingBundle\Doctrine\Phpcr, Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\MenuBundle\Model, Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\MenuBundle\Doctrine\Phpcr

What does it mean and how to heal this strange behaviour?

Also, does anybody have a good explanation or tutorials how to use this great Symfony-CMF things?

Comment: Please note that Symfony CMF is still under active development and has not released a stable version yet.

Comment: @Touki, thank you for editing. I'm feeling a pretty big bunch of emotions right now. I understand that it is not stable version now, but I feel that the solution for my problem is very simple, but for some reasons I can't see how clear it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error looks like you did not activate any storage layer for the CmfBlockBundle. Do you have something like

```
cmf_block:
    persistence:
        phpcr:
            enabled: true
```

If you also use the CmfCoreBundle, it is enough to have it enabled there, as the CmfCoreBundle prepends this configuration to all cmf bundles.

```
cmf_core:
    persistence:
        phpcr:
            enabled: true
```

Comment: You are perfectly right! But how did you get it? I don't understand :(

Comment: And now when I'm trying to open /app_dev.php/admin/dashboard it throws an error: Cannot import resource "/home/user/www/sites/example.com/app/config/." from "/home/user/www/sites/example.com/app/config/routing.yml". (Please define a default `baseRouteName` value for the admin class `Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\BlockBundle\Admin\Imagine\SlideshowBlockAdmin`)

Comment: Maybe it is because I'm trying to include CMF in my already created project... Because when I'm trying to run clean CMF install (standalone) it gives me a chance to select sqlite db adapter

Comment: ftr: there is now a lot of documentation at http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/index.html - configuring databases happens in the parameters.yml and phpcr.yml config files.